# Redirect to old site if content is not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, cpanel

We have recently deployed new site as the old site was giving us a lot of problems and its a news site.
We have changed the old site to old.domain.com and made the new site as domain.com. Before people used to visit old site on domain.com which is now shifted to old.doamin.com. To shift the content from old site to new is not possible.The site was 4 years old and a lot of content were shared from the site like domain.com/xyz/abc but when now people come to visit those old shared link they will be directed to new site domain.com/xyx/abc where the content will not be found as the content is now shifted to old.domain.com/xyz/abc.
So I want to achieve redirection so that when the people click old shared link domain.com/xyz/abc they will be redirected to old.domain.com/xyz/abc only changing domain so that the content can be displyed from old site. Site is hosted in apachel in cpanel.

I have tried the following in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://old.domain.com/$1 [P]

</IfModule>
```

P.S I am not a programmer but I am trying to achieve this for my company.

Comment: What form do the URLs take at the "new" site (`example.com`)? Do they all map directly to physical files? Or are they "virtual/pretty" URLs (which would seem more likely for a "new" site)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to redirect URLs from `domain.com/foobar` to `old.domain.com/foobar` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule . https://old.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This will redirect all requests received on `example.com` to `old.example.com` . If you have some files and folders on the `domain.com` that should not be redirected then use the following instead :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . https://old.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

If this works then change `R=302` to `R=301` to make the redirection permanent.

Comment: ++ but do mention that by using `.` in regex pattern it will skip landing page for redirection i.e. `domain.com/`

Comment: I will try @amitverma solution once I get approval for downtime (incase if there occurs problem). What I want to achieve is if a page shared from old site (i.e. before implementing new site )https://example.com/abc/xyz must now be redirected to https://old.example.com/abc/xyx but if a page is shared from new site say https://example.com/def/zxc then it must not be redirected to old site as the content is valid in new site. What I want to express is if a content is found in new site don't redirect but if a content is not found in new site redirect to old site. Both sites are live.

Comment: This does assume that URLs at the new site all map directly to physical files, which seems very unlikely these days for a "new" site. (?)

Comment: @abckdc Is there a _pattern_ that differentiates `/abc/xyz` (old URL) from `/def/zxc` (new URL)?